# Almost sure convergence of harmonic mean

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation, law-of-large-numbers, almost-everywhere

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim Uniform(0,1)$. Harmonic mean is defined as:

$H_n = \frac {n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{X_i}}$

Find a.s. limit of this as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I already did the problem for both arithmetic and geometric means which relied on SLLN and CMP theorems. In the case of harmonic mean expectation of $1/X_i$ is infinite so I can't use SLLN.
I feel like the limit should be 0 but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> An elementary pointwise comparison will do...

For every positive $t$ and every $n$, $H_n\lt H_n^{(t)}$ where
$$
\frac1{H_n^{(t)}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{X_n+t}.
$$
By the SLLN, $H_n^{(t)}\to h_t$ almost surely when $n\to\infty$, where 
$$
\frac1{h_t}=E\left[\frac1{X_1+t}\right].
$$
Thus, for every positive $t$, almost surely,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}H_n\leqslant h_t.
$$
Since $1/X_1$ is not integrable, $h_t\to0$ when $t\to0$, hence, almost surely,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}H_n\leqslant0.
$$
Since every $H_n$ is nonnegative with full probability, this shows that $H_n\to0$ with full probability.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105236) for all you ever wanted to know about this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This indeed helps, however, your proposed solution requires some additional constructions outside the scope of the standard probability course. Do you have any hint on how to solve this problem in 10 minutes(that's how much time we have for it on the test)?

Comment: Good way to sell your research and also a bit of an overkill? :P

Comment: @Lost1 Our paper answers this set of questions _completely_ (for all sorts of distributions of the input variables) -- I am quite proud of the results, and I am pretty sure that if you were to read it you would learn something. As for whether this is the right level for someone's exam question, I don't really give a rat's behind. If you understand the material, you will do well on exams.